# Obtaining Sentinel 1 imagery from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am trying to obtain Sentinel 1 imagery from Google Earth Engine using a script (link to script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3d11cd9919f33e8649e9b35e3f5c05e). This worked perfectly for 2017 imagery but when I try to download imagery for 2016 I get the errors below in the console.

stack
Image (Error)
Image.select: Pattern 'VV' did not match any bands.
Feature.id: Parameter 'element' is required.
S1 radar filtered: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'VV' did not match any bands.

Can anyone suggest how I might fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Could you add your area of interest. It might be that the 'VV' data for your area of interest doesn't exist for that time period. I gather you checked this with:

```
print('temporalFiltered', temporalFiltered);
```

Be adviced that using `mosaic()` function composites all the images regardless of the pixel values, meaning that if one image contains false values, this will impact the whole mosaic. Either checking each image before using them in the mosaic or masking out bad images should work.

If you are interested in having your mosaic contain highest pixel values for a specific band from the imagecollection, you can use `temporalFiltered.qualityMosaic('band name')`.